# SpringExstension.class JUnit5 dependency как добавить [SOLVED]

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, тестирование

Хочу написать интеграционый тест для дб - в приложении используется контекст спринга.

Нагуглила возможость использовать **расширения junit5**, но при попытке найти соответствующую зависимость - провал. Подскажите, что это за **зависимость**, позволяющая **подключить к приложению spring контекст для тестов**?

(п.с. само приложение не построено на спринге, и уж тем более на spring boot - используется только context)

Возможно, я конечно нашла то, что мне нужно - junit-engine, но не уверенна, то ли это. Поскольку, для mockito требовалась отдельная зависимость расширения junit, и еще приложение не наследуется от спринга и ничего кроме контекста не использует, поэтому есть вероятность, что необходимо будет подключить какие-то дополнительные модули...

**UPDATE**

Добавила зависимость :

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Вкупе с junit-jupiter-engine и junit-jupiter-api все еще не работает

```
Test ignored.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter.and(Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter;)Lorg/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils$MethodFilter;

    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.<clinit>(SpringExtension.java:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.registerExtension(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.MutableExtensionRegistry.createRegistryFrom(MutableExtensionRegistry.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ExtensionUtils.populateNewExtensionRegistryFromExtendWithAnnotation(ExtensionUtils.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:143)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.prepare(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

**UPDATE**

Пыталась еще добавить spring-boot-starter-test, не сработало(

Answer (score 0):

Вопросик решился. Главные необходиые зависимости из pom.xml:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.3</version>
      </dependency>

<!--      Test-->

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.7</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.4</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Пришлось немного повозиться чтобы разобраться с дублирующимися заисимостями и несовместимостью версий, но, вроде все получилось:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(TestConfiguration.class)
class CategoryRepositoryTest {

    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CategoryRepositoryTest(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    @Test
    void findAll() {
        Category category1 = new Category("Some category", Collections.emptyList());
        Category category2 = new Category("Some another category", Collections.emptyList());

        category1 = categoryRepository.save(category1);
        category2 = categoryRepository.save(category2);

        List<Category> expectedCategories = List.of(category1, category2);
        List<Category> actualCategories = categoryRepository.findAll();

        assertTrue(actualCategories.containsAll(expectedCategories));

        String PATH_TO_PROPERTIES = "src/test/java/resources/sql-connection-test.properties";
        DatabaseUtil.deleteCategory(category1.getId(), PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);
        DatabaseUtil.deleteCategory(category2.getId(), PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);
    }
}
```